# Numerically solving the equation of motion for inflation in cosmology

Tags: cosmology, computational-physics

So I want to solve the equation of inflation involving a scalar field numerically using python libraries such as odient or scipy. The equation is:
$$\def\phi{\varphi}
\phi''(t)+3H\phi'(t)+V'(\phi(t))=0$$
with given condition: $3Mp^2H^2 = V(\phi)$.
Can anyone help me with the code and advice on how to progress on this?

Comment: Perhaps a better fit for https://scicomp.stackexchange.com

Comment: Implementation details of computational tasks are [off-topic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on this site: “While computational physics is on topic, we are not a programming site. If your question is about implementing computational code - in particular, if it's about writing, compiling, debugging or optimizing code, or about a specific language or library - then it is off topic. It may be suitable for Computational Science or Stack Overflow, however.”

Comment: You can ask conceptual questions about computational problems, and you should make them *clear*. Isn’t $H$ supposed to be a function of $t$? Do you know what $V(\varphi)$ is? Are $M$ and $p$ constants? How will you choose initial conditions? Do you understand that the primes on $\varphi$ and $V$ are different derivatives?